# jquery fails with dropdown menu selection action

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am performing action on dropdown menu item selection.

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A4aMK/1/)

but does not make any action when I test on localhost, even does not show menu item. Though I have included all files.

code:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> 

    <script>
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
    alert("hi");
      var selText = $(this).text();
      $('label').css('color',selText);
    });

 </script>
    </head>
<body>
<label>Test color</label>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-btn btn-default">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span class="caret"></span>

            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">yellow</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">green</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">black</a>

                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">red</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /btn-group -->
    </div>
    <!-- /input-group -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What's wrong with this code?

**UPDATE1**

```
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    alert("hi");
      var selText = $(this).text();
      $('label').css('color',selText);
    });
 </script>
```

No change

the result looks like this:

[image]

UPDATED CODE:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src=" http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
<link href="css/bootstrapa.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    

    </head>
<body>
<label>Test color</label>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-btn btn-default">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span class="caret"></span>

            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">yellow</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">green</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">black</a>

                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">red</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /btn-group -->
    </div>
    <!-- /input-group -->
</div>
    <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert("hi");
      var selText = $(this).text();
      $('label').css('color',selText);
    });
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you are setting click handler before element is available in DOM. As a simple fix, use document ready handler. BTW, you seem to not include jQuery at all and including boostrap CSS and JS twice. Please, read some basic tutos before asking (next?!) question...

Comment: @A.Wolff: see update1, but still no change

Comment: Your js code is not wrong, double check on your console window.

Comment: Dropdown menu also does not work. I think css is also not getting calle

Comment: You're fiddle seem to work and you're code is fine. something else going on with your local.

Comment: That update actually will work if you put it correctly.  You replaced your old function, you needed to just supplement.  Note the difference in this fiddle (on the left menu with the jQuery option) when you use it with and without the `$(function() {...});` in it http://jsfiddle.net/Y6Vpj/

Comment: Isn't `$(` deprcated in new jquery?

Comment: @Deryck: still issue persist. Dropdown menu item also does not appear. css itself has some issue

Comment: wait do you mean the dropdown menu as in... before clicking the arrow?

Comment: Are you missing a jQuery lib reF? I'm just seeing the jQuery UI Ref

Comment: @Deryck: yes, when I click arrow, it does not popup items

Comment: @FelipeKM: you talking about which files?

Comment: @user123 I'm guessing that above your jQuery UI you need a ref for the jQuery Lib

Comment: @FelipeKM: I added the snap of result. well ` <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` is this not enough?

Comment: You need to refer jQuery Lib, I will change my Answer below.

Comment: lol nice catch felipe.  Yes you need both, and jquery has to come first, then jquery ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
<body>
<label>Test color</label>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-btn btn-default">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span class="caret"></span>

            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">yellow</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">green</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">black</a>

                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">red</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /btn-group -->
    </div>
    <!-- /input-group -->
</div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>         


    <script>
        $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
        alert("hi");
          var selText = $(this).text();
          $('label').css('color',selText);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks you very much. it works. The problem was only in positioning the external link and scripts?

Comment: Yes, you got it. Take careful when using jQuery or any lib that depends of it, if you have jQuery code before you refer the jQuery lib it will not render properly. Plus, try to always put your scripts refer before your </body> close tag.

Comment: Yes I guess, these are the last releases of it.

Comment: by the way, what is difference between `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.css`?

Comment: The diff is the min version is the minify version of it, here is the concept: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44351/discussion-between-user123-and-felipekm)

Answer (score 1):

Try to include the jQuery lib before your jQuery UI refer.

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I could not understand. please show me which file you talking about

Comment: Put this code before your jQuery UI refer: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Got it?

Comment: gives `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Comment: Yeah, you need to put your scripts above '</body>' tag and the first one need to be the jQuery and then jQuery UI, Bootstrap and after all you can include your '<script>$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){.....'

Comment: hey @user123, I did here on my machine, I will post the entire code asap.

Comment: thanks for your efforts. I put final updated code. No error but menu items are not visible

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").on('click', function(){
    alert("hi");
      var selText = $(this).text();
      $('label').css('color',selText);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the click function when the document is ready. In your edit, you just try to move the code from the click function the `$(document).ready()` function. In that context `$(this)` does not refer to the select element. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
        var selText = $(this).text();
        $('label').css('color',selText);
    });
});
```